# STOP c00021a after CHKDSK

Tags: windows-7, boot, bsod, chkdsk

Windows 7 recently did ran CHKDSK at boot time on my Windows 7 laptop, the HP Pavilion dv6-6135dx. After the system finished checking the disk, on which it did find problems, it rebooted. I then was presented with the following blue screen: STOP c000021a. The initial system process exited with a status of 0x00000000 (0xc0000001, 0x00100778). I have access to a recovery partition with a command prompt and an Ubuntu installation on which I can modify the Windows files. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why was the CHKDSK running in the first place?  Some background as to any other problems you were having might be helpful.  (Also, do Safe Mode or Last Known Good Configuration work?)

Comment: @Shinrai CHKDSK ran because it runs every x reboots by default on Windows 7. Last Good Configuration does nothing, and I'll try safe mode right now. I was not having any other problems prior to this.

Comment: That 'default behavior' is news to me.  Hmm.

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/how-to-disable-the-chkdsk-check-disk-on-start-up/35f58c69-7a6c-4e1b-aec3-26d7131ec643

Comment: There. evidence it is the default behavior. By the way, Safe Mode gets the same blue screen.

Comment: Huh.  To my knowledge, that isn't actually out of the box behavior for stock Windows 7, and I say this as a system builder with a ton of machines in the field.  There are plenty of ways it could get scheduled, and maybe get stuck on, but it shouldn't be like that out of the box.  Hmmmmmm.

Comment: Huh. I dunno, it's always been like this on this laptop for me.

Comment: It's pretty weird - I wonder if the manufacturer did that by design?  I will also say, anecdotally, that I've never seen it on my own personal machines.  It's not terribly relevant here, I don't think, since it seems like you probably didn't have anything hugely crazy going on first, so I'll quit jamming up the comments. :) (And unfortunately this particular stop error isn't one I have a lot of familiarity with, so I'm not much help here.)

Comment: @William Automatic check disk Only happens if the volume is marked with a dirty bit by Windows, so the word automatic is misleading, it only runs automatically if severe file system corruption or bad sectors is detected by Windows. More than likely you have a failing hard drive, I would back up your data using a Linux Live boot CD and then replace the hard drive, then use the HP Recovery discs to re-install the OS.

Comment: This computer is 3 months old, the hard drive should not be failing. I want to know how to fix the error code.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic check disk Only happens if the volume is [marked with a dirty bit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc788091%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) by Windows, so the word automatic is misleading, it only runs "automatically" if severe file system corruption or bad sectors is detected by Windows. More than likely you have a failing hard drive, I would [back up your data using a Linux Live boot CD](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/use-ubuntu-live-cd-to-backup-files-from-your-dead-windows-computer/) and then replace the hard drive, then use the [HP Recovery discs to re-install the OS](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01895783&cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en#RestoreWithDiscs).

You can run diagnostics on the hard drive to verify a failing hard drive, [diagnostics can be accessed in the bios](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00439024&tmp_task=solveCategory&cc=us&dlc=en&lang=en&lc=en&product=5118737)